# Docker Ram Utilization

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am currently experiencing some sort of memory leakage on docker desktop, I am running one container at the moment but the service 'Virtual Machine Service' is currently sitting at around 8gb it doesn't change after restart my PC.

Rebooting machine did not fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is a memory leakage issue. In Settings/Resources/Memory section of Docker Desktop, you might see that 8GB is allocated and you can change this value. Mine was also 8GB, I am guessing Docker allocates half of the available memory (16GB in my case) but I could not see it written in the config options doc.

Hope that helps ;)